# Handling large amounts of markers on google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Question is based on experience with googlemap api V3 otherwise please ignore the question**

**Summary of the question:**

- question consits of a lot of information (background information about use case), but the question have only 
  2 clear and specific parts
- part one is about [clustering markers](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)
  an its using in this case
- part two is about loading new markers
  (respective loading new groups of markers) when you move with view
  port
- both parts are still about same thing about handling with the points (markers) in the viewport, when you solve one you have to think on second part and otherwise

**Info about the usecase and desribing of the question** 
Imagine application of hundreads or thousands points (places) defined by latitude and longitude which are stored in database. I will show the places on the maps. Map will be divided this way:

- the map will be divided to regions = center of the map will be set to some specific latitude and longtitude from that region region (for example the main city of the region) - for simplicity it will be 2 known coordinates
- the number of regions is < 20
- in each region will be some routes, each route will consists of some points (like you have road map and go from one city to another city and there are some towns on the way for example town1, town2, town3 => so you have 5 points - only the points are important)
- region consits of < 100 routes, each route consists of < 100 points (=places/=towns) (by point understand latitude and longitude coordinates)
- so I mentioned 3 types of dividing my area: regions > routes > paces in route; this are dividing what you will be able reach from menu of my web application (=php+html5+css+js)
- next thin what is important are the places - number of places would be in thousands and sence of all of it is that you choose some starting point and wanna show the nearest places ( for example region1 -> route 2 -> city 4 on route 2 its on latitude x and longitude y and i wanna show only relevant place in viewport = places around the city 4 on route 2)

**There are some problems which comes up: (the bold are important for me)**

- storing the places in db (MySQL) maybe not best idea, I'will consider
  some sorting places by coordinates to some groups for easier requests
  to db
- too many places in viewport (for exmple city 4 on route 2 is center of the map and there are 50 or 150 places aroud it) - I found
  some soulution as [clustering the places](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) - **question part 1** is if
  somebody have experience with that and if its enought for running it
  on normal computer or mobile browser (don't wanna kill the app by
  tunes of markers on the viewport) - what I read this can group the
  markers together and show more specific if you zoom in
- problem 2 is moving from one region to another (or just moving from the place) - example you have center point of the map called A
  (=city 4 on roadmap 2) and in the view port there are loade only
  points which fits to this view port, then you move with the map to
  the right and you should load new point cause your viewport is
  changed = **question part 2** is what could be good practise for loading
  that points - if you turn "10 pixels" to the right call the db for new places, then you turn "another 10 pixels to the right" again call db for another new places is stupidity, cause I would kill app only by requests for db, sorting, etc.

Comment: There shouldn't be a part 1 and part 2 of your question. Just create two separate questions.

Comment: @AlexW but bot parts are about same thing - showing the points 1 parts is zooming problem second part is about moving the the view port but when you do one action you have to still thing about the boudaries of the viewport and the points in the view port, so I think it shouldn't be separate

Comment: You can still reference (provide a link to) the first question, in the second question. The main benefit of separate questions is it becomes more simple to read and answer. I would also think a jsFiddle or screenshot would be very helpful in describing the problem.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Comment: @geocodezip looks as interesting article, by briefly going throught it looks I believe it could help, btw I found on your profile page http://www.geocodezip.com/ and it would be also rly helpful for anybody who wanna do anything with google maps :)

Comment: @AlexW ok, thx for advise, I'll consider it. I was thinking about it, but there are anyway too much haters which likes to downwote so they will probably criticise why I link two questions ... 
jsFiddle - can't use it, and at the momet it's all in my head so rly don't have a cue screenshot of what or presenting what in jsFiddle did you expected ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bounding box to filter most of your places. Then use the harvesine formula.